# .htaccess rewrite for date i.e. /2012/12/31

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls, multiple-value

I am trying to create some rewrite rules to organize content by date via URL in a short, readable way.

i.e.

```
http://mysite.com/post/index.php?a=Dave&b=2012&c=12&d=31&e=1
http://mysite.com/post/index.php?a=Dave&b=2012&c=12&d=31
http://mysite.com/post/index.php?a=Dave&b=2012&c=12
http://mysite.com/post/index.php?a=Dave&b=2012
http://mysite.com/post/index.php?a=Dave&b=all
```

becomes

```
http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012/12/31/1
http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012/12/31
http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012/12
http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012
http://mysite.com/post/Dave/all
```

This is the .htaccess I have in //mysite.com/post/

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4&e=$5 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?a=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?a=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now the problem is some of the URLs don't work. From the above examples, three of them work as expected. but the others output in these ways:

```
URL: http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012/12
OUTPUTS:
    a => Dave
    b => 2012
    c => 1
    d => 2
URL: http://mysite.com/post/Dave/2012
OUTPUTS:
    a => Dave
    b => 20
    c => 1
    d => 2
```

And this is obviously not the correct values, apparently splitting up the number across the other variables.

Why does it do this and what must I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't say `/?` everywhere. The `?` means that the preceding expression is optional. This means that `2012` matches `([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)/?`, because those slashes don't have to be there. What you want is `([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?`, because you want that the slash *at the end of the URL* is optional.

Comment: So that must also mean I don't need to double all the rewrite rules for a leading slash? The solution works wonderfully and has fixed other similar issues I've had, thanks!

Comment: A leading slash would be a slash at the beginning, so I assume you mean a trailing slash. Yes, that's exactly what you would use `?` for. It seems you were using them in all the wrong places, and none of the right ones ;)

Comment: Yes, trailing slash. I found a page where they were using it like that and I had thought it was something to do with where the variables and patterns match up, which in retrospect seems pretty ridiculous.